# MySql Trigger for Updating PostCount

Tags: php, mysql, select, triggers

I have three datatables: comment, blog and user. I don't know much about Triggers in MySql, but is it possible to sum up the counts of every Row in comment and blog when a new Row is inserted or deleted?

E.g. blog has 3 entries and comment has 5 entries. When I delete one comment now, it should update the record 'post' in user to 7 by counting the entries in blog and comment by the username.

comment table rows: id | cdate | edate | author | email |status | content | url | bid | level

blog table rows: id | cid | author | cdate | title | teaser | content | url

user table rows: id | username | email | pass | posts

Answer (score 1):

EXAMPLE TRIGGER FOR comments update event you can write slimier triggers for all other events change highlighted values

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS comment_delete;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER comment_delete AFTER DELETE ON comment FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

UPDATE user set posts=posts-1 WHERE id=new.author;

END$$
```

Comment: comment_update - trigger name ;  After Update -- event ; comment -- table

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but I'll get the following error message: #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger...What is this commit?

Comment: yes  i have done a small mistake we canot access same table within its on trigger ill update the answer

Comment: updated answer on delete you can reduce one from original post count and on insert you can add 1 to excising post count

Comment: Solved my problem. Thought I need to write the delimiter part in the phymyadmin window, but obviously I just needed to write the Query Part.